# saving current ip addresses in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am looking for a good way, to show how much people are accessing my website currently (live).

I figured out, that it would be probably the easiest way, when i save the ip address of the person, that accessing my server/site, in an mysql table.

so what i probably have to do is:

creating an well configured mysql table

adding the feature (i guess in php) of saving the ip address

adding the feature of deleting the ip address, if it isn't needed any longer

making the process realtime or close to realtime

Can somebody help me?

Comment: We'll be happy to help you. What is the issue with the code you've written?

Comment: The easiest way is to integrate a Google analyze tag and let them do the counting. The IP address is way to little to get reliable data. You will also need at least cookie tracking.

Comment: Have a look at [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) - it'll do your stats tracking for you.

Comment: well, i am kind of at the begin of the project and i am new into all that php and mysql stuff! it might be a to hard problem to start with, but it really would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, may I suggest that this question isn't titled very well? It's a typical mistake for people to 2nd guess what the solution for a problem is when asking for help - I see this all the time in current/previous companies I've worked when staff are submitting bug reports.

The thing that you're trying to achieve is implementing some form of analytics so you can determine how many people are visiting your site, how many of them are unique visitors, and also being able to see realtime data of who is currently using the site. So a better title would be something like "How can I get information about who is visiting my site?".

Storing ip addresses in a table is a valid way of achieving this, but is far from ideal. I'd highly suggest using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) (or something along those lines) as this will enable you to see all of this information and more, plus it won't require very much effort on your part. You don't even have to be a coder - you just copy and paste the snippet they provide into your HEAD tag. There is plenty of information out there about how to do this so I won't go into detail, but don't hesitate to ask if you're having any problems.

Comment: Thanks! I am really happy, that You explain to me, how I should work on this problem. I have to look if Google Analytics is a good tool to use. The only problem I have is, that I don't want to have a "longterm" statistic about who is visiting my site, what I actually want to have is a tool that is showing, how much people are "right now" on my website/server. So its going to be a text like this:

"8" people are currently available

The value of how much people are available should be always up to date. I am sorry for not making my problem as clear.

Comment: You're in luck, Google Analytics now provides exactly this! After you've set up a "tracking code" and have embedded the snippet of code to every page of your site (normally just once in the layout template) you can log in to your account, click "Home" on the top navigation bar, then "Real-Time" on the left navigation bar. This is currently in beta, but it works great for me. As an additional bonus, not only can you see "X active visitors on the site" - you can also see what page they're on and how they found your site.

Comment: Cool, well sounds like thats exactly what I need. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick example of how you might go about getting the real IP address of a client and then storing and retrieving its value from the mysql DB

```
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
//The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
$ip = ip2long($ip);
//The $ip would now look something like: 1073732954
```

Now that you have the real IP address of the client converted to the INT format, you can write it into the DB as you normally would

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(ip) VALUES('$ip')";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql,$dbLink);
```

More on this link: **[Best way to store IP addresses in MySQL](http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/)**

additional information: to make you code safe from **[SQL Injection](http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO user(ip) VALUES(?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $ip);

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: thanks. I have to see if this helps me (i am not that big of an coder, so it will take me a while to try out the code).

Comment: @user1644622 try also using PDO extension.

Answer (score 2):

Store your visitors into the database (like the other answers). Use a `datetime` field wich holds the date of the last request of the visitor (you have to update the row every pageview).

Now u can calculate the "currently online visitors" by using MySQL interval.

For example:

```
SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `online_visitors`
FROM `visitors`
WHERE `datetime` > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECONDS
```

Answer (score 1):

This is functionality that is already built in with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), `IP` addresses aren't the best way of keeping track of visitor count.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a page is requested, you can push the IP Address to the MySQL Database, so that it would be unique.

```
<?php
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    mysql_connect();
    mysql_select_db("visitors");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `visitors` (`ipaddress`) VALUES ('$ipaddress')");
    mysql_close();
?>
```